# Как в переменную записать true (булевый тип), если в тексте есть слова из списка?

Tags: javascript

Есть список [[BLACK_LIST]]

```
night
year
when
you
can
```

Есть текст [[TEXT]] тип строка:

```
night has rolled out redesigned 3d hd
```

Как задать в переменную [[EXIST]] true (булевого тип), если в [[TEXT]] есть слова из [[BLACK_LIST]]?

В **[[TEXT]]** и в **[[BLACK_LIST]]** все буквы строчные будут.

Делал когда-то js-код для удаления из многострочного списка строк которые есть в блеклисте:

```
[[TEXT]] = [[TEXT]].filter(function(line){
  return [[BLACK_LIST]].every(function(forbiddenWord) {
    return line.toLowerCase().indexOf(forbiddenWord.toLowerCase()) === -1;
  });
});
```

Но вот как проверить одну строку и присвоить булевый тип в результат - ума не приложу((

Comment: [[TEXT]] по виду, это массив с массивом... Для просто строки можно воспользоваться indexOf()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Строку разбить на массив. Предположим, что `[[TEXT]]` это и есть массив слов из текста.
2. Далее применить

   ```
   let result = [[TEXT]].some(el => [[BLACK_LIST]].includes(el))
   ```

В `result`  будет `true`/`false`

Comment: спасибо. всё получилось